# android_asset not working on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a shipping Android application that displays occasional static webpages that are included in the assets folder.  I have been displaying these programmatically like:

```
webView = new WebView(PKBDocument.KnowledgeBook.KBContext);
setContentView(webView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/path/to the/file.html");
```

This works fine for API levels 3 - 9.  I just recently received my shiny new Xoom and tried running the same app, and I get an error

`The webpage at file:///android_asset/path/to%20the/file.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address`

So, I started experimenting.  The Honeycomb emulator displays these pages just fine, but my actual honeycomb device (running 3.0.1) consistently displays this error.  I can read the webpage with AssetManager and then display it using `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, but then the image links in the web page don't load (presumably because it can't find the path to the image file).

Any idea what changed, and how to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the space. [This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb1) and [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb2) both work fine on my XOOM.

Comment: Sure enough, the space was the problem - strange that it seems to be perfectly OK on all earlier editions of the SDK.  Ah well... thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jeff Hay: Well, it's probably a regression, though it may be a regression to return to a standard. I took an educated guess on the space because your `file:///android_asset/path/to the/file.html` isn't a valid URL with the space. You could try manually URL-escaping it to %20 and see if that helps -- I've never tried that.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had tried manually escaping to %20 before I posted the question - as well as running it through URLEncoder, neither of which worked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Strange. I have the same problem. but with «file:///android_asset/help.html». It does not get more simple but it still does not work.

Comment: There is also a bug reported: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19293 — seems a fairly common problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that I compiled with maven. With maven your assets should go into `src/main/resources/assets` and I had them in `src/main/resources` — which apparently is wrong.

It seems that Honeycomb stricter about this. If you don't use Maven then make a listing of the files in your apk file (it is just as zip file) and check that your assets correcty inside the asset directory:

```
7z l target/*.jar

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Listing archive: target/HP45-Droid-5.0.0.jar

--
Path = target/HP45-Droid-5.0.0.jar
Type = zip
Physical Size = 465392

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2012-01-01 19:07:10 D....            0            0  META-INF
2012-01-01 19:07:08 .....          125          102  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2012-01-01 19:07:06 D....            0            0  assets
2012-01-01 19:07:06 .....        93692        93629  assets/45bk.jpg
2012-01-01 19:07:06 .....         3467         1408  assets/help.html
```

Comment: +1 For the 'teach the developer to fish' style answer. Never really thought about just opening up the apk and looking inside before. Note for Windows devs: I couldn't open up the apk as a zip with the default windows extractor, even after changing extension to .zip. Downloaded trusty old 7-zip, though, and it had no trouble showing me the files inside.