# white space allowed as part of file path?

Tags: android

My question is kinda related to [android_asset not working on Honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365780/android-asset-not-working-on-honeycomb)

Is it allowed to have spaces in the file path name of an html page located in the assets folder?

For ex: Is the following legal?

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Help File/helpfile.html");
```

Is there any other solution other than renaming the "Help File" directory to have no spaces in it?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Use %20 instead of space. URL has to be URL-encoded.

Comment: mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Help%20File/helpfile.html"); does not work :(

Comment: even URL-encoding did not work either - String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode("Help File","utf-8"); mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + encodedString + "/helpfile.html"); Interesting i observe that the UrlEncoder is replacing the white space with a "+" character [as explained in the google developer's doc] and not a %20 as i would have expected.

Comment: I am using Xoom device Android 3.1 OS version. I tried bunping down the target version to API level 8 or 9 and that did not help. May be it's the Xoom device itself that's acting weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use a URI, which will address such issues.

```
mWebView.loadUrl(new URI("file:///android_asset/Help File/helpfile.html"))
```