# Universal Image Loader for external storage files

Tags: java, android, java-io, universal-image-loader

Hello I use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)  to load images from the device , now it works, but if the file path contains a "space character" the image does not get displayed and log records show that there is a `FileNotFoundException` .

I tried to open the file in a thread using java io and it opens and I can read it.

the file name :

```
/mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20121014-WA0001.jp
```

when the Exception thrown
it replace the space with a `%20` and this what makes the exception thrown.

My code:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                    Uri.fromFile(
                            new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(

                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)))).toString(),
                    holder.mImage);
```

works only when no spaces in the path ,

Any help

Comment: have you tried to replace space symbol to `%20` ?

Comment: check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478295/white-space-allowed-as-part-of-file-path

Comment: LogCat's stacktrace? Lib version?

Answer (score 12):

The other answer unfortunately isn't too clear on what `fileName` is so after some additional digging I managed to use local image with imageloader using:

**Sample Code:**

```
string imgPath = "/mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20121014-WA0001.jpg";

String decodedImgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath)).toString();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(decodedImgUri, imageView);
```

[Android loading local image with space in path and with universal image loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815417/android-loading-local-image-with-space-in-path-and-with-universal-image-loader) also helped to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found this solution.

```
String uri = fileName.getUri().toString();
String decodedUri = Uri.decode(uri);

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(decodedUri, imageView);
```

Comment: fileName is your File object

Comment: You saved me alot of time :) Thank you! This will also helps if file name has non-ascii symbols.