# Load Image with Universal Image Loader using the Path of Image

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am trying to load an image with UniversalImageLoader. I tried this way:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/BlackHole/Black Hole/1gatopan0000.png"

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(path, viewHolder.imageView);
```

But nothing happened. Is it possible to load the image using UniversalImageLoader with the path of the image as a string?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29815763/343679

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to add a backslash before any space character in your path.

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/BlackHole/Black\ Hole/1gatopan0000.png"
```

Then, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a great library that allows you to load images easily. I personally find it prettier than the UIL. In order to load an image into your ImageView, you simply have to :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("/your/path/here").into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: How can i convert the spaces in \

Comment: `path = path.replaceAll("[* *]","\\ ");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/BlackHole/Black\ Hole/1gatopan0000.png"
```