# Android video compression using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression, filenames

I am compressing video using ffmpeg library.
user can browse for any video and compress it. It is working fine for videos with video name don't have white spaces.But if video name have white spaces compression is not working.we try to double quote for video path but still it is not working. for eg. our video path is like this - `/storage/sdcard1/Video/teri jhuki nazar.mp4`

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to encode the URL (replace the white spaces with `%20`) ? Or try making an URI like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478295/white-space-allowed-as-part-of-file-path) ?

Comment: yes i have tried the following command but still it is not working                 ffmpeg -i /storage/sdcard1/Video/teri%20jhuki%20nazar.mp4

Comment: try to rename file first withoutwhitespace.after compress rename to original

Comment: @Nikhil Desale, I am trying to integrate  FFmpeg library in my android app but  I am not getting the proper idea after adding dependencies. how to use FFmpeg inside my activity to reduce the videos.Can you give me some idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **ffmpeg** each commands are separately identified using white spaces.
When you specify a path having white spaces, the path will splits according to white spaces and will be considered as different commands and hence the error arises.

[**Here**](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/hiteshsondhi88/sampleffmpeg/Home.java#L146) you can see how each commands are differentiated.

I suggest you to make your own changes in command styling and differentiating.

---

Refer :

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Answer (score 0):

Replace white space with "\ " like

```
String filePath = "/storage/sdcard1/Video/teri jhuki nazar.mp4";
        filePath = filePath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

OR

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/sdcard1/Video/teri%20jhuki%20nazar.mp4
```

Comment: My commend is :  "ffmpeg -y -i "+picturePath+" -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";   it is not working for only video name having space

Answer (score 0):

use following sample code to avoid blank spaces in your video file.

```
String temp = URLDecoder.decode("Your file path");

String videopath = temp;
```

then send videopath to ffmpeg. It's goona work.