# Problems loading html asset into webview

Tags: android, webview, assets

I am having difficulty in loading a html file from my project assets folder into a webview.  I have looked at dozens of tutorials and solutions but none seem to work for me.

In my project's assets folder I have two simple html files.   index.html and faq.html
(The plan is to utilise this structure for my help documentation)

My code:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
          @Override  
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
          {  
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
          }  
        });         
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

The webview displays the following:

```
Web Page Not Available

The Web Page at file:///android_asset/index.html could not be loaded as:

The requested file was not found. index.html
```

From everything I have read what I have here should work, but it does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webview load html from assets directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your usage is right, so if has this problem, you need check the **index.html** file existed or not carefully, also you can **clean the project**, and rebuild it.

Comment: I have done a project clean with no result.  How can I test if index.html existed?  Is there a way to check the contents of the apk that ha sbeen installed on the emulator?

Comment: the project path has a bin folder, the apk will save to here, you can use the zip tool to extra the file, you can check the asset folder.

Comment: Try accessing some other web page...if that loads then problem lies with index.html....there does not seem any error/problem with the code you have posted.

Comment: I have opened the apk and neither assets/index.html or assets/faq.html are in the apk.  Do I have to manually include the assets folder to be included?  I thought eclipse did this automatically when setting up the project.

Comment: I think I have found the cause of the problem.  My project comprises of the project and then a separate library project.  I was placing the files in the /assets folder of the library project which was not working but when placed in the /assets folder of the main project it works fine.  I just need to figure out how to include the /assets folder of the library project in the apk.  Thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try this code ....
```

WebView myBrowser;

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String myURL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        myBrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

        /*By default Javascript is turned off,
         * it can be enabled by this line.
         */
        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myBrowser.loadUrl(myURL);

    }
```