# Error in load html + JavaScript in android

Tags: android

I did try samples, demos from Google codes and other resources with WebView, but when i try to do it in my own code, it doesn't work for me.

I want to load index.html which i put in assets folder, and using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //define webview
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

On emulator i cannot see my file its still white background and not open my index.html.

Note:-

my index.html is include JavaScript than get data from web site online by ajax.

Is there any way of loading an existing .html file in the application package which works on all API versions ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

Edit :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 1000);
           }
         });
         webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         });

         webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");   
}
```

i will try this code but i have error :-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - WebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setWebViewClient(WebViewClient) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (new 
     WebViewClient(){})
```

Comment: what happens if you put some text into your html? does it show up?

Comment: @Axarydax no i cannot see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152491/enable-back-button-in-webview/16152530#16152530 check the edit 2 in the link for a working sample

Comment: @Raghunandan i will try your code but i have error, see my update post

Comment: have you imported import android.webkit.WebViewClient; check your imports

Comment: @Raghunandan i am sure import it

Comment: @kammaik works fine on my samsung galaxy s3. i only added my own index.html to the assests folder. I din't see any error. Run the code on the device and check

Comment: @Raghunandan i try but i have the same error

Comment: @kammaik did you try opening the same in a browser on your mobile

Answer (score 1):

If your `index.html` includes JavaScript code, try:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i will try but this code have error :-
`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
its need something !!

Comment: @kammaik Have you tried `webView.getSettings();`?

You can also try: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: @kammaik Have you checked those links:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583010/opening-an-static-html-page-in-webchromeclient-in-android-gets-added-with-some-m
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737488/problems-loading-html-asset-into-webview/8737547#8737547
?