# Does Android WebView support frameset tag?

Tags: android, tags, webview, frameset

My `WebView` need load a html.

```
  <frameset rows="59,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="files/top.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frameset cols="213,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="files/left.html" name="leftFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="leftFrame" title="leftFrame" />
    <frame src="files/mainfra_.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
  </frameset>
  </frameset>
```

Does Android `WebView` support `frameset` tag?

Comment: Wouldn't it take you less time to point your Android device's browser to a webpage containing the questionable html, than it would to post a question and wait for someone to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [webview-load-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory). And anyway your frameset tag in html, when html file runs in android then automatically it will support frameset tag.

Comment: is it helpful this link to you.