# How to run files on Android device from local server?

Tags: jquery, android, html, android-emulator, local-storage

I want to HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery files on my Android device from local host or local server on the Android.  I tried to save files and run them in the Android and Mozilla browser to run files but it's not working.

Comment: save that html file in assets and load that html file to webview.for reference see the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Comment: where is the assets folder on android device

Comment: not in the device .asset folder is exist in your android  application

Comment: that means i can not run the files directly from the local server i have to run files from android application

Comment: yes,If u want to run the html file in android device u have to use android application

Comment: what is ur problem .tell me exactly

Comment: i was creating a Webpage with HTML5, CSS3 and using jquery, i want to run that webpage on android tab, and i want to save the files on android tab want to run those files from there, i don't want to run files from online server because files take much time to run from web server while if, I run those files from local folder, than i can open those files easily and there is no need connect with internet to run those files....so tell me how can i run those files....somebody told me to do that with local server or by giving the path of file like entering the URL file:///sdcard/post.html .

Comment: That's why I was thinking to create local host on android device and run files from there.....Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

save that html file in assets and load that html file to webview.for reference see the below link [Load html5 to webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can!
Use htmlview application to open .html from android memory card or internal memory
or
use html5 offline cache aka manifest to make it offline so when you type www.yourtestxdomain.org/yourapp.html it just works without online connection.

or install webserver in your android.