# Webview popup not working

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am trying show a pop up dialog with an image inside from a webview when clicked. my problem is that the pop up dialog is not being pop up but it open full screen inside the webview or it open in a browser. is it possible to make pop up inside webview ? i used the following 
websettings but it proved fruitless.

```
WebSettings settings = wvcontent.getSettings(); 
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

this is my html content.

html_content =

```
"<strong>"+title+"</strong>" 
               + " <br><br><img src='"+single_image+" width='300' height='211'>" 
               + "<br> " 
               + ""+ content + "<br>"
               + str 
               + "<div id='popup' style='display:none'>"
               + "<a id='popup-close' href='' class='button'>"
               + "Fermer" 
               + "</a><p><img id='image-placeholder' width='300px';height='250px'  src=''>"

        + "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js'></script>"
               + "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  $(document).ready( function() {
                        $('.popup-open').click( function(e)" 
               +        "{$('#popup:visible').hide(); 
                         e.preventDefault();

                 $('#image-placeholder').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));" 
               + "$('#popup').fadeIn('fast');});
                  $('#popup-close').click( function(e) {e.preventDefault();                                                        $('#popup').fadeOut('fast');});});" 
               +"</script>";
```

can someone provides a hint please ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a normal popup window, you should try using a modal dialog.  This will open in the same page, on top of the active content.  I believe, on Android, what you are attempting to do with pop up's is not possible.  They will always open in a new window.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: where can i find an example for android?

Comment: It doesn't have to be specific to Android since you are using a webview combined with jquery.

Comment: i have done this but its not filling my modal dialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517028/display-div-content-in-a-modal-dialog-box-in-java#comment18504146_13517028

Comment: Why are you trying to use a webview? Have you thought about using a regular Android Dialog? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: The images are from html content i want to avoid lazyload image

Comment: Maybe you could post more of your code. Maybe i'm missing exactly what your try to do.

Comment: i have images displayed in 3 by 3 row and column. when i click on one image it pops up wide in a dialog box.  i tested it on browser it works fine but on webview its not the case.

Comment: Maybe try including all of your html, js, and images inside the android project. And then load the html directly into the webivew. The same thing was accomplished here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Comment: its a good example but my html content are dynamic and asset content are static.

Comment: But your loading it in a browser, right? So you've got to have a .html file.  Try loading that in the webview using the method above.

Comment: its working when loading the .html file inside the asset folder but not the dynamic way.

Comment: Guess i'm not understanding why the HTML needs to be dynamic.

Comment: because the links are loaded from a web server to the android application

Comment: Have you considered using phonegap? http://phonegap.com/  Load your html within the phonegap webview.. then build a phonegap plugin to dynamically retrieve the links from the web server.