# Change background color in an HTML webview

Tags: android, html, webview, background-color

I have a HTML Webiew in an android application and I want to change the background of a TD element on an OnTouch event.

How do I do that by HTML / javascript / or CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some starter material:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

http://api.jquery.com/click/

[Webview load html from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)