# Html5 and javascript app to Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an html5 and javascript app, something like google maps, but for an offline enviroment (and much more simple). Is basicly a big image (not so large) and, you can drag or resize the map and view some information that we add. I have not added any native function at this point.
If I run the app with the android default browser, it works perfectly, but when I include it in a phonegap application, the image quality is so bad, and when I drag it, the event works, but only for a split second.

I have heard that phonegap has performance issues, so, it is a phonegap problem?
If so what other way would you recommend me to take my android application without having to completely rewrite it?

Comment: just implement a WebView and load your html from assets folder. Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Comment: +1 to the comment above; WebView should do all of this for you.  There may not be a ton of features to play with, but it should work nicely.

Comment: no, same thing happens with the WebView, I think that ultimately it will be a performance problem, I have no more to think. I think using Leflet will be the solution