# How to draw Stacked Bar Chart in Android Application

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am new to Android. I am on a project and trying to draw stacked bar chart. I did so much research about this kind of bar chart but either those didn't work or I couldn't apply the codes to my project. 
I guess there are two most popular libraries for charts which are AChartEngine and Charts4j. I checked this code (https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/BarChartExample.java#51)- example1 for Charts4j. However, this code ends with 'url', I have my values in my project, I'll use these values to draw the chart and I don't want to have to have internet to show the chart. I want to be independent from the internet. I couldn't implement this code to my project.

Another library I used is AChartEngine and I found this code (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java). Because the main class extends some other class, I created other class (AbstractDemoChart) and interface (IDemoChart) and wrote the codes. Eclipse didn't give any error but when I run it on Emulator, I got an error which stopped the app and the warning of 'force close' appeared.

The other examples about bar charts are not relevant what I want exactly. As a result, I couldn't find any solution for my application. Can you help me how to draw stacked bar chart for my Android App with the values that I already have and I want to see this chart  independently from the internet?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know native android library or extensions to do that, can be difficult to find a good one ore implement a new other.
For this i think that you have just used a library HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I think that you can implement with a js library the graph, for example [Javascript graph](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html)
, charge the html/js files in assets and charge it into a web view with this:

[html app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

The only problem is to find a way to pass data to the html, i think that is it possibile in various way, with bridge or using files.

Answer (score 1):

[Androidplot](http://androidplot.com) supports stacked bar charts as well.  Screenshot from the [Androidplot demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidplot.demos) on the play store:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download the AChartEngine demo source code and take a look at [SalesStackBarChart](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java). Then, on the last line, you can change `Type.STACKED` to `Type.HEAP` for an even better stacked bar charts experience.