# Running website on Android Device from file

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I have a web application I've built using the Jquery mobile framwork and I need to put it on my phone for demonstration purposes. What is the best way to go about this I was going to use phone gap but I want and easier solution say I just put the files onto my phone and run it from within the device but I don't know if that's possible. If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opendroidphp&hl=en

Comment: You could create a small container app consisting of a full screen `WebView` (with activated JavaScript) and bundle your files with your app by putting them into the assets directory of the app project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap build would be the easiest way! Here is a link to the documentation http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans(en)! It gives you a qr code to download a test to your android device before releasing, sorry no ios tho!

Hope that helps! Littleswany

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple WebView work for you? You can also use local files instead of downloading the site/assets from a web server.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of another way, If you have adobe cc then you could use edge code and edge inspect and the android app to have a test server on your device.

Sorry for the second answer but again I hope it helps you! Littleswany!