# can`t webview load html page from assets folder

Tags: android, android-webview

in my app not load html page from assets folder and not error are occur and screen are display as blank

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlviewer);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            setContentView(R.layout.htmldesplay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `setContentView` before getting `WebView`

Replace your code with this

```
setContentView(R.layout.htmldesplay); 
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlviewer);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

instead of

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlviewer);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
setContentView(R.layout.htmldesplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

set  setContentView(R.layout.htmldesplay);

before

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlviewer);

Answer (score 0):

It happens...
"You need to set the layout using setContentView and then initialize views."
Take care..

Answer (score 0):

**You are getting the `WebView` before setting the `Content view` so the `webView` is probably null.**

**Try this,**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");



}
```

Refer [Webview load html from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)