# Android Webview load json file from local

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have problem in the android `WebView` while loading `JSON` from local folder, the data is large that is why I didn't host it on the server. I get this error,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/MyApplication/app/src/main/assets/data.json?format=json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You can't dynamically load file from your PC. Place it into the phone first.

Comment: You cannot make an AJAX request to the local file system, ie `file://`. You need to host the code on a webserver and make the call to that location instead

Comment: in my android solution i created folder name assets have website files and json file i want to read data from this file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory