# How can I declare a Large String(<Html> codes) in Java to avoid "Constant string too long" error?

Tags: java, android, html

In `Java` I am using a large `String` for `<Html>` codes which meant to create a complete designed **email body**.
eg.

```
String msg= 
            "<html>"+
            <BODY CONTENT>
             "</html>";
```

Problem is I am getting error "constant string too long”. 
I need some ideas if anyone of you have solved this issue or faced this.

Comment: make substrings

Comment: @Stultuske You mean inside Strings.xml ?

Comment: where did Strings.xml come from? I mean't, instead of saying String a = "abcdefg..."; you say String a = "ab"; String b = "cd"; ...

Comment: Use a string resource. Use a raw resource. Use an asset.

Comment: `String msg= 
            "<html>"+
            <BODY CONTENT>
             "</html>";  ??? That will never compile. Do you mean: `String msg= 
            "<html>"+
            BODY CONTENT
            + "</html>";` ?

Comment: You can store your file in assets folder and retrieve it from assets. hope this link will helps you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Answer (score 2):

There is limitation the Constant string but  one can have a much larger String in memory as long as it is created at run-time such as by reading it through a resource.

**You can try this solution.**

```
private static String msg = null;

public static String getMyString() throws IOException {
    if (null == msg) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("msg.txt")))) {
            msg = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
   }
    return msg;
}
```

You can call it and save it in another string :

```
String str = getMyString();
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

**or you can build your string with the string builder.**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
sb.append("<html>")
      .append("<body>").append(bodycontent)
      .append("</body>")
      .append("</html>");
String result = sb.toString();
```

Hope this is helpful. cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is not so many things we can do when facing `constant string too long` error.

Constants are constrained to 64K elements per single String entry, but you can split your exceeding constant in a couple of smaller than 64K ones as a workaround.

In terms of software design, at the other hand, the idea of working with complete email bodies as just Strings is not ultimately perfect. Usually developers are using **template engines** for such purposes and do externalize email bodies to a separate files rather than String constants. Please see [Chunk](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/wiki/index.php?title=Chunk) template engine as example which fits well into Android app, but there are lots of another such as [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/). Template engine lets you clearly separate **static** email content from **dynamically-populated** pieces, separate your application data model from it's html representation, and maintain valid architecture of your software

Being not aware of exact reason which prevents you from making a file instead of constant, there are lots of best practices to solve typical file-connected issues starting from embedding files into your jar as resources and ending in encrypting them to avoid unwanted leakage. Just ask another question on SO here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [StringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), e.g.:

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(here_put_size); //change string size, default value is 16 characters
msg.append("<html>");
msg.append("<BODY CONTENT>");
msg.append("</html>");
return msg.toString();
```