# loadUrl is working with link not for local html page (In fragment not activity)

Tags: android

Requirement is to load local html page in Fragment.I can able to load external links, getting issue when i give file path for local html page.

Error:- file_not_found

able to load external links no issue using Loadurl()
ex:-
     view.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?wizard=1");//working
     view.loadUrl("file:///assets/"+fileName);  //not working

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {
WebView mWebview ;
public String fileName = "help.html";
public FiveFragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_five, container, false);
    mWebview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.loadUrl("file:///assets/"+fileName);
    return view;

}
}
```

Comment: Looks like `help.html` is not immediate file under assets . if its inside another directory  then you need to provide  directory   name also . And i think it should be  `mWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+fileName);`.

Comment: no it is under assets

Comment: Make sure that you are providing correct filename or path.

Comment: @ADM is correct

Comment: `file:///assets/"+fileName` is not the way to load assets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview load html from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

Comment: no, it is not duplicate, reference you have provided extends activity, here it is fragment  , given in oncreateview() without return it raises error

Answer (score 0):

Create assets folder in your main directory where java and res directory exists then paste your html file in assets folder and load it with your below code.

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/homeremedies.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the HTML file is placed under the assets folder

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");